# i feel over-above-on the moon metaphor

Tags: metaphors

- I feel over the moon.
- I feel above the moon.
- I feel on the moon.

What's the difference between the three sentences above and what I should prefer to express an ecstatic sense?

Comment: Only the first one makes sense. The others are incorrect.

Comment: The main difference is that idiomatically, only *"I am **over** the moon"* (less frequently, *"I **feel**..."*) occurs.

Comment: This is part of the [`UP/DOWN` metaphor array](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf). The moon is `UP`; one's emotions are `UP`; therefore you are in the vicinity of the moon, emotionally. _Over the moon, high as the moon, moonstruck, mooning over, up to the moon, go to the moon_ and others, all work, in context. Generally you don't need the _feel_, though; one does this in a conversational context that is **about** feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom is **over the moon**, to describe being ecstatic. The other phrases do not exist as idioms, at least in US English.